# can't get data from table with huge row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't get result data from table except I use limit on the query

```
 $this->db->where('PrshStatus', 'A');
 $this->db->where('PrshJenis', '1');
            
 $this->db->limit(22); 
 return $this->db->from('TPerusahaan')->get()->result();
```

This code is working, but when I remove `$this->db->limit(22);` the code isn't working

Comment: Check your php timeout value

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: isnt working? is there an error message we can see?

Comment: no error message is displayed and no results are displayed

Comment: What is this? I can see two queries and one return

Comment: i'm tried to retrieve data from a table

Comment: As you said you have huge rows, then you have to add php timeout. Otherwise I will suggest you to use `limit` with offset.

Comment: Also look into your table, are PrshStatus and PrshJenis indexed if the table is very large and taking too long to return results. Search stack or google for "mysql identify slow query"

Comment: PrshJenis already an index